# exe requires the .NET desktop runtime

Tags: c#, .net, exe

I have developed a exe file by using windows forms app and setup project in microsoft visual studio installer. While executing that exe it will show some GUI and ask for some user input (eg. next, install). This exe is created on my system and it is executing in my system. But when i run the same exe file in various machines it shows message (you must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application). After installing .NET Desktop Runtime on that machine, it works properly. Can we have some other solution to run the application without installing the .NET Desktop Runtime ?????

I have be trying to install the .NET desktop runtime while executing the application that is working, but my aim is to run the application without installing the .NET desktop runtime on the machines.

Comment: You can either build the Setup GUI based on pure Win32 without using .NET, or install .NET before showing the GUI.

Comment: You should read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) and also follow some of the pertinent links from that page, including the ones for framework-dependent and self-contained apps.

Comment: If the goal is to write an installer, I would suggest [Wix](https://wixtoolset.org/) instead of writing one yourself. It is not particularly easy to use, but it is fairly powerful and customizable, and likely more reliable than your home grown installer.

Answer (score 3):

From this article [Publish with Visual Studio - microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trim-self-contained#publish-with-the-cli)

> The alternative is to publish a self-contained application, **where the .NET runtime and runtime libraries are bundled together** with the application and third-party assemblies.

That gave us two solutions:

- using visual studio to publish
- using dotnet cli to publish

### With Visual Studio

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the project you want to publish and select Publish.
2. Choose More actions > Edit.
3. In the Profile settings dialog, set the following options:

   - Set Deployment mode to Self-contained.
   - Set Target runtime to the platform you want to publish to.
4. Save the settings you just made in step 3.
5. publish

### With Dotnet CLI

If using CLI, `dotnet publish -r win-x64` should work for you.

The CLI option `-r` means **Publishes the application for a given runtime**, You can find the RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER(RID) you need here [.NET RID Catalog - microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

Answer (score 0):

C# does not build into native code, but into an intermediate language. So, if you build a C# application and aim to run it on a machine, the given machine will need to be able to interpret this intermediate language. This is why your users are prompted to install .NET if they did not already do so.

However, you can work around this, by converting your C# code into C++, which you can do manually (but the labor to be performed to do so increases proportionally with the size of the code to convert) or automatically with some tools. Example: https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/csharp_to_cplusplus_converter_details.html

Now, if you converted this, then you will need to make sure your new C++ project works well and have the proper makefiles. Then you will always need to test it at machines where .NET is not present, just to make sure your C++ code does not rely on .NET prerequisites.

You will likely need some resources you use as dll files, linked to your project.